# Objective-C/iPhone - oAuthException when using "me/checkins" as part of the Facebook Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am receiving the following graph response when checking users into Facebook using the Facebook Graph API. I am using the [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/facebook-ios-sdk) within my iPhone application to do this.

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."}}
```

I have not made any changes to my code today and I know for a fact (database logs, etc) that their have been successful checkins yesterday.

I'm asking the SO community whether or not they have received similar errors and how they attempted to resolve them?

I have already tried the following:

1. Revoked access to my application via Facebook.
2. Reset my `offline_access` token by forcing Facebook to generate a new one.

Keep in mind my application successfully shares via peoples Facebook walls as well and this is working as expected without any problems.

I request the following permissions from my users:

```
@"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"publish_checkins", @"email"
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, so this is quite strange and I'm thinking that it's an error on Facebook's end.

I use the following code to tag friends in the checkin:

```
if ([self.selectedFriends count] > 0) {
   [variables setObject:[self.selectedFriends componentsJoinedByString:@","] forKey:@"tags"];
}

fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/checkins" withPostVars:variables clientId:accessToken];
```

`self.selectedFriends` is simply an `NSMutableArray` of Facebook profile ID's separated by commas, which is what the graph API says to use and remember this has been working fine for months.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

If I remove the `[variables setObject:[self.selectedFriends componentsJoinedByString:@","] forKey:@"tags"];` then the checkin works just fine for *me*.

It fails every time I tag one or more friends. Is anyone else receiving the same error when tagging friends in a checkin?

**UPDATE 1:**

Looks like other people are receiving the same problem relating to Groups:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=349396

I wonder if there's a bug at the moment relating to Checkins.

I've posted a bug:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18134

**UPDATE 2:**

Facebook were able to reproduce [the bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18134) and they're now looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m using checkins in one of my applications , Regarding your issue ,

Yes , you are right , i had this OAUTH Exception only when sometimes you made checkins continuously with tagging friends,

Also allow permissions like @"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins", in your application

please check this link :

http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [dictionary objectForKey:@"place"], @"place", //The PlaceID
                               coordinates, @"coordinates", // The latitude and longitude in string format (JSON)
                               message, @"message", // The status message
                               tags, @"tags", // The user's friends who are being checked in
                               nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate: postCheckinRequestResult];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For some reason adding "user_checkins" and "friends_checkins" has fixed the problem completely. I wonder if Facebook have added those as prerequisite permissions in order to tag friends but have forgotten to add them to the http://graph.facebook.com/ documentation? I am waiting for them to get back to me via bugzilla so if it's okay I won't accept the answer until I've heard a proper resolution from Facebook themselves. Thanks for all your help.